# Is it possible to have something similar to Next.js API routes in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing some applications using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages. And I know that many times I need to connect to backend only to send and receive data, and no view is in the process.

NEXT.js has the concept of `api route` which works perfectly for this scenario.

Do we have something similar in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you do not need to return a View in your controller methods, you can return JSON too

```
public JsonResult ReturnJSONMethod()
{
    return Json(...);
}
```

Comment: I meant a separate file. A code-behind file only.